# Import data from .xls File

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, xls, csv

I am developing an application in which i have to get data from .xls file. I am fairly new to iPhone development so any pointers in direction to getting started will be very much helpful.

The steps that i am thinking are :

1) First i need to convert from .xls to .csv Format.

2)Import the data from .csv file to SQlite Databse or Core Data.(I am not familiar with any one of them, so kindly suggest which one to choose. I am looking forward to use Core Data)

Am I thinking in the right direction? Will be greatful for any kind of assistance..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the import a one time thing or is it gonna be a scheduled process?

Comment: It is a one time thing, at the start of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot speak to the first part of your question, I can give you advice for the second.  Because you are importing the data as opposed to writing back to the xls format, you want to go with Core Data. There is no reason to be using sqlite directly anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think sqlite is a good idea if you want to be able to use the same datastore with multiple different devices in the feature. If you are targeting iphone only then go with core data. Also a sqlite datastore can be loaded back in with core data on top at a latter date if you want all that caching ability.